# Force 404 error for Coldfusion REST API

Tags: api, rest, coldfusion

I've been developing an API for a ColdFusion app using their [built in RESTful webservice](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/coldfusion/articles/restful-web-services.html). I'm running into a problem though with invalid url pathways. Normally if I hit an invalid directory such as `https://myapp.com/invalid/path/` Coldfusion will throw a 404 but if I hit an invalid url under "/rest" such as `https://myapp.com/rest/invalid/path/` then I get a blank 200 response and in my error logs:

> "Application  could not be found. - Application  could not be found.
>   null 
> The error occurred on line -1."

Instead of this behavior I want my application to throw a 404 when an invalid pathway is being hit. Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Comment: Any chance you are using CF2016? I call bug on this one.

Comment: No, we're still on CF11. But I think you may be right that this is a bug.